# Auto populate columns in one sheet from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I would like to populate columns in sheet2 from sheet1. If I have column `A` in `Sheet1` I want `A` in `Sheet2` to have the same information.

I tried using `=sheet1!A1` but it only returns the value from `A1` in `sheet1`. I tried using `=sheet1!A` but it only returns `#NAME?`.

If Column `A` from `Sheet1` has a dynamic range (it can be empty or have 500 or 1000 rows (I'm populating sheet1 from my database)). How do I use some of those columns in another sheet showing all 500 or 1000 rows?

Comment: -sheet1!a1 will work.  put it into A1 onsheet to then copy/paste the formula down and excel will auto-increment the forumla.  If you are wanting to process the entire column at once with VBA, there is an answer below that covers that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below code will look for last used row in sheet1 and copy the entire range from A1 upto last used row in column A to Sheet2 at exact same location.

```
Sub test()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 7):

If I understood you right you want to have sheet1!A1 in sheet2!A1, sheet1!A2 in sheet2!A2,...right?

It might not be the best way but you may type the following

> =IF(sheet1!A1<>"",sheet1!A1,"")

and drag it down to the maximum number of rows you expect.

Answer (score 5):

I have used in Google Sheets

```
 ={sheetname!columnnamefrom:columnnameto}
```

Example:

1. `={sheet1!A:A}`
2. `={sheet2!A4:A20}`

Answer (score 3):

In Google Sheets you can use =ArrayFormula(Sheet1!B2:B)on the first cell and it will populate all column contents not sure if that will work in excel

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'EntireColumn' property, that's what it is there for. C# snippet, but should give you a good indication of how to do this:

```
string rangeQuery = "A1:A1";

Range range = workSheet.get_Range(rangeQuery, Type.Missing);

range = range.EntireColumn;
```